# How do I apply the HoloEverywhere android theme when using ActionBarSherlock?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-theme, android-holo-everywhere

I'm building an application that should work on android 2.3 and I added both ActionBarSherlock and HoloEverywhere libraries.

In order to use ActionBarSherlock  I have to use Theme.Sherlock like so :

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"
    ...  >
```

And that's ok.

My main activity is pretty simple : just a ListView with 5 rows (I don't use ListAcivity).

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/menuListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Since it's android 2.3, I still have the orange&black theme (except for the ActionBar of course). Now I want to add the HoloEverywhere theme by modifying my manifest like so :

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/Theme.HoloEverywhereDark.Sherlock"
    ...  >
```

BUT that does not change anything... What am I missing ?

Comment: i need the spinner like ICS in previous versions. But i tried importing ActionBarSherlock and Holoeverywhere. But in eclipse after importing throwing lot of errors. And also please tell can't we just use holoeverywhere without ActionBarSherlock ?

Comment: which errors? and yes you can use Holoeverywhere without actionbarsherlock

Comment: Like resource not found errors. Step i did to import is->File->New Project->Android Project From Existing code.

Comment: Check that the R.java file is correctly generated, sometimes it's not. Also you should set ActionBarSherlock project as a library in the properties of HoloEverywhere project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To enable the Holo theme by default for every ListView I went in the styles.xml file of the HoloEverywhere library then I modified the "ListViewStyle" element by adding this line :

```
<item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/list_selector_holo_dark</item>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with ListView's selector. I though that HoloEveruwhere would apply holo selector(blue) by default(I have tried both Theme.HoloEverywhereLight and Theme.HoloEverywhereLight), but it didn't. Maybe I am missing something.

I ended up setting the selector manually:

```
listView.setSelector(R.drawable.list_selector_holo_light);
```

You have several drawable resources in the library you can make use of(list_selector_holo_light for example).

Comment: that's actually working but then I have to do it for each ListView.

Answer (score 2):

A portable and correct solution would be to inherit from ListViewStyle and override the attribute, making this in your styles.xml.

If you had HoloEverywhere official library deployed remotely on a server (e.g. Maven repo) you could not depend on it mantaining a change in the styles.xml (you are modifying it for your own needs).